# when the file changed ,I read the file , the content of file is always the same?

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader, inputstreamreader

I use watchevent provided by jdk1.8 to listen the file change event,but when the event come ,I read the file ,however, the content of file is always the same? 
**watch file change event code:**

```java
final WatchKey key = watcher.take();

for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {
    // get event type
    final WatchEvent.Kind<?> kind = event.kind();

    // get file name
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") final WatchEvent<Path> pathWatchEvent = (WatchEvent<Path>) event;
    final Path fileName = pathWatchEvent.context();

    if (kind == ENTRY_DELETE) {
        log.info(String.format("%s文件被删除",fileName));
    } else if (kind == ENTRY_MODIFY) {
        log.info(fileName.toString());
        log.info("ENTRY_MODIFY");
        if (Constant.ERROR_LOG.equals(fileName.toString())) {
            String filePath = "\\\\192.168.160.128\\share\\error_log";
            int totalLine = FileUtils.countFileTotalLine(filePath);
```

**Read file code:**

```java
File file = new File(sourceFilePath);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "utf-8"));
StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
String sLine = null;
while ((sLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    strBuilder.append(sLine);
    strBuilder.append("\r\n");
}
```

Comment: About three minutes later,the bufferReader can read the newer file content,why?How can I read the updated file content immediately?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a similar issue my application using the Watcher service when it was waiting for kind == ENTRY_MODIFY on a file, but nothing like the 3 minute lag you have. Your code is incomplete, so its not clear whether there is an important bit missing which explains that lag so it would be nice to see the full code.

Unfortunately the watcher service can generate a storm of events per file especially ENTRY_MODIFY. I found it much more reliable to call watcher.poll(timeout) in a loop, and collate the events received in a set. Only act once if set gets large, or once watcher.poll returns null, or some time interval since last processing. Something like:

```
var modified = new HashSet<Path>();
while(runningFlag) {
    WatchKey k = ws.poll(modified.size() == 0 ? 10 : 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    if (k != null) {
        // Loop through the ENTRY_MODIFY events as before but save the items:
        ... modified.add(fileName);
        if (!k.reset()) { ... handle reconnection  }
    }

    if (modified.size() > 0 && (k == null || modified.size() > limit)) { 
       // Act on modifications set
       ...
       modified.clear();
    }
}
```

This will reduce the number of events you act on though you may have some other network mount / caching issue to deal with here too.

Comment: Does a standalone program on same machine see changes from the network share contents within the 3 minutes?